# In docker container how to run another container command?

Tags: docker

Example:
I have a image ubuntu and another image mongodb.

How can I run mongod(mongodb command) or another mongodb image command when I'm running ubuntu image.

Comment: You use docker to isolate processes.

Comment: update: there are some solutions now:
https://forums.docker.com/t/access-to-docker-command-from-host-inside-a-container-with-java-program/28300/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Any image will generate one or more containers.
- Every container is isolated of others.

If you can run MongoD inside a Ubuntu based container you need to install MongoDB inside your Ubuntu based container.

But, if you need connect on mondodb to create a user, change settings of your mongod instance, **you don't need a second container**, on mongodb container you can execute commands to perform that.

On mongodb documentation at docker hub, the example about mondodb security talks about it, the example explain how to connect your shell to container, and show how execute `docker exec -it [mongodbContainerName|mongodbContainerId] mongo admin` to get access to administration of mongodb using console.

Comment: Then it means I can not use ubuntu image shell to execute mongodb image command?

Comment: On docker any container receive a virtual IP. Containers can talk with others if on same network or if you have a link from caller to called container. To execute mongod or mongo in ubuntu based container you will need to install a new instance of mongodb on this container. Execute commands out of your container, you need to run docker exec,  inside your ubuntu container, and your ubuntu container needs a new installation of docker (you use only cli - docker, not dockerd). With this approach you can execute the mongod on remotely container from ubuntu container.

Comment: If you explain the big picture of your needs, maybe i can find a answer for you.